# How can i use 3 characters to filter a Select2 Matcher?

Tags: jquery, search, jquery-select2

at the start sorry for my english. Im trying to use a filter in a select2.

I need to write 'otr' in the browser select text and then, with all data in the select, i need to get de text "Otras" directly at the first place. I get all data by json, got all the things that i need but i dont know how to make this filter

I dont know if the matcher needs an event to execute or it dids atuomatically when you directly call on the method. But well, the first that i need is the implementation and i dont know how to connection the text that i have to write in the browser (text is 'otr') with the option of the select who calls 'Otras'

I think i have to use matcher, and i created a function like this to do the filter:

```
 function matchCustom(params, data) {

        if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
          return data;
        }

        for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
            var terms = term.split(" ");
            var filtro = new RegExp("\\b" + terms[i], 'i');
            if (filtro.test(text) == false){
                return (text === 'Otras Ocupaciones')
            }
        }

        if (typeof data.text === '') {
          return null;
        }

        if (data.text.indexOf(params.term) > -1) {
          var modifiedData = $.extend({}, data, true);
          modifiedData.text += ' (matched)';


          return modifiedData;
        }

        return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Fox, i dont know why he didnt let me put the function into the code